# How to solve $x$ for an equation with $x$ as an exponent and an argument of a logarithm?

Tags: logarithms, wolfram-alpha

I have the following equation:

$$2^{-\frac{1}{x}}+1=-\log_2\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)$$

I can't find a way to solve it.

I got it by the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+2^{-\frac{1}{x}}}$ when I was finding the point where $x=y$. For this I inversed the function, resulting $f^{-1}(x) = -\frac{1}{\log_2\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}$. Equated and simplified results in the firts equation. I know is simpler to equalize $f(x)$ and $x$ and solve it with the Lambert's W function, but I was wondering about the first one, considering Wolfram Alpha can't solve it step by step (does it solve by testing?) and both equations returns same value for $x$, being something different.

Plot:

[image: Plot]

As you can see, there is one single point where $x=y$.

Comment: You suggest that there's only one such point, is this actually the case?

Comment: Furthremore, solving your equation will not give you a fixpoint of the function $f$. It's a different prolbme. Essentially the problem $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. don't even know what this is good for or does make any sense...

Comment: $x \approx 0.72289208118314779553236535121977167435587773676864172$, $2^{-\frac{1}{x}}+1  \approx 1.38333234798106154655560221125515742400333767333491602923$

Comment: @JürgMerlinSpaak Please, see the graphic.